# How avoid buffer overflow on Epson EPOS (via serial port)?

Tags: c#, escaping, serial-port, epson

when I print huge data on my Epson TM H6000 or TM-88II, the printer buffer gets full and not all data will be printed. I use c# and SerialPort to send data (via ESC) to the printers (doc: http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/3/ajj-TM-H6000_DeveloperGuide.pdf).

Is there any way to avoid buffer overflow?
Or should I reduce the data weight and send more little packages?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Alex

Comment: Here is the best manual I was able to find: https://code.google.com/p/version-two/downloads/detail?name=ESC-POS-Command-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This is from the document you linked:

> When the remaining space in the receive buffer drops to 16 bytes, the printer status becomes “buffer full” and it remains “buffer full” until the space in the receive buffer increases to 26 bytes ... The printer ignores the data received when the remaining space in the receive buffer is 0 bytes

...

> Check the printer status using GS I or GS r after transmitting each line of data
>   and use the 4KB receive buffer. Transmit one line of data so that the receive buffer does
>   not become full.

This sounds like perfect advice for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply!

I tried to send GS l and GS r, but I got no response (status byte). I'm right, that this should work by using DataReceived method?

Kind regards
Alex

Comment: Yes, the response should come in on `DataReceived`, but if the receive buffer's already full, the commands will be ignored. Do you get no response even if it's the first command you send? Note also that `DataReceived` is [not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx), so you should probably check `BytesToRead` after sending the command anyway. Also, make sure DIP switch 1-2 is off...

Comment: +1 for actually helping rather than closing this question. This is the only useful QA on SO for the ESC/POS command DLE/EOT and it is closed?! Again, SO fails people trying to get real work done.

Comment: FYI: pdf I linked in initial comment says `GS a` is the "enable" for transmission of automatic status and is required for `GS r`; however, it would seem no one manual is definitive how any of this works and testing will need to be done to determine your exact printer's abilities.